# Google Charts different behavior between pie and column charts

Tags: javascript, charts

When drawing a series of numbers in a pie chart, Google Charts automatically sets different colors for each slice. Exactly the same set of data could be used to draw a columns chart. In this case, all columns are shown in the same color.

I found some posts describing how to display a columns chart with different colors for each column (a *hardcoded* example in Google's documentation), but when I want to create the same structure programmatically, I get errors.

My question is: given the hardcoded example:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
     ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', 'Cu' ],
     ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', 'Ag' ],
     ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold', 'Au' ],
     ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', 'Pt' ]
  ]);
```

how can I programmatically generate this very same structure?